# How to access blocked website, e.g. Bluebox - Error 500?

Tags: proxy, browser

When ever I try to access the shopping websites from blue-box. It says:

```
"An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. Error code: 500"...!
```

How do I resolve this?

As suggested by many I have tried to access the same page giving it some time. Disconnecting the connection and reconnecting it again. But nothing is working out.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What is blue-box? Also the error you get says that the error happens on the server side so, if you are not yourself the administrator of the  server I don't think you can do a lot. Except maybe send the said website a kind e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

[Error 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a server side error, you, as a client, can do almost nothing to resolve that error. The only thing to get over this is to try after some time.